# How to get username and password of windows authentication from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, evopdf

I need to pass WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION details of logged in user to the pdf converter to make it work.
I've tried this

```
PdfConverter.AuthenticationOptions.Username = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.UserName;
PdfConverter.AuthenticationOptions.Password = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Password;
```

But this doesn't help. Converter is working locally, but returning 404 errors in the server where windows authentication is enabled.

How can I get credentials with the code?

Comment: Do you really need to specify your application user credential to an external PDF convertor. Sound scary... Have you tried AuthenticationOptions.UseDefaultCredentials, its default to true but only when you do not specify UserName?

Comment: Unfortunately, we have a license only for an old version which doesn't have UseDefaultCredentials property. AuthenticationOptions has only two properties for me(Username and password).

Comment: Yes, it looks scary for me too, but I can't imagine another solution here...

Comment: You have a license hence the right to ask for feature that are secure enough. Have you contacted their support team and confirm this? If not I suggest you do that, may be worth.

Comment: The whole point of windows authentication is that the password is never passed to the remote endpoint - just proof that the user knows/knew their password at an appropriate recent point in the past.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, And how in that case AuthenticationOptions.UseDefaultCredentials works?

Comment: Surely in this case you need to setup a Service Account (that is a windows user that only sys admins / devs know the details to) and use those credentials. Is there any reason why the current users credentials have to be passed?

Comment: @Gab - basically, you've received a blob of bytes that prove the user knew their password. Depending on which exact security features you're working with (NTLM vs Kerberos and local vs remote) the windows security system may allow you to impersonate the user (without knowing their password) or delegate for the user (again, without knowing their password). But that depends on API support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:- (You can use [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
WindowsIdentity id = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
String UserName = id.Name;
```

I don't think we can retrieve password since passwords are **not** stored in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to the latest version which uses the credentials of the current Windows to access the web page from IIS. This can be disabled if you want with HtmlToPdfConverter.AuthenticationOptions.UseDefaultCredentials property